# For bin/magento indexer:reindex catalog_product_attribute running for unlimited time

Tags: magento2

For production site it's work well.

When we try to use master-slave marriadb then it's running for unlimited time.

A picture is attached, where the query is on Copying to tmp table is running for unlimited time.

Any clue.

Magento - 2.2.7 (CE)
Database - MarriaDB 10.1.x
Master-Slave (Read-write)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following optimization:

```
optimizer_switch='rowid_filter=off'
optimizer_use_condition_selectivity = 1
```

[More detail](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/performance-best-practices/configuration.html#indexers)

Comment: optimizer_use_condition_selectivity is already set to 1.
According to doc it's says for MarriaDB 10.4.x version but i am using 10.1.x version.
still i need to use the configuration.
FYI, it's working well on another server.